# Beep sounds when error using speaker

Tags: raspbian, gpio, pi-3

is it possible to add this speaker to Raspberry pi 3 via GPIO to get indicated by beep on error.

[image]

How should I plug it in where on GPIO ?

Comment: Try this connect the red wire to a GPIO pin and black to ground.then toggle the GPIO pin just like you would flash an LED.

Answer (score 1):

An expansion on Steve's comment on OP

This is the pinout of the Pi3's GPIO, it's oriented so that if you have the USB and ethernet ports at the bottom, the top right pin (5v, pin 02) will be at the top-right of the Pi.

[image: Pi3 40-pin pinout]

Choose a **GPIO** pin (one with GPIO*nn* in the name, *green* in the pinout) and connect the **red wire** to it, and then connect the **black wire** to any **ground pin** (marked in *black* on the pinout)

Then to make the speaker sound, here's an example in Python (unable to test so feel free to edit). For this example, the **red wire** is connected to **pin# 11 (GPIO17)**

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO #Import the GPIO library
import time #Used for waiting between beeps


speakerPin = 17 #Use GPIO numbers for Python, not pin numbers
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(speakerPin,GPIO.OUT) #Sets the speakerPin as an output pin
GPIO.output(speakerPin,GPIO.HIGH) #Turns the speaker ON
time.sleep(1) #waits a second
GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW) #Turns the speaker OFF
```

By using this (or equivalent in another language) wherever an error may occur in your program, you should achieve what you're looking for.

Hope this helps!

Comment: well if you look at image closely  between red and black pins there are two wholes minding that i had to connect red one to GPIO21 i.e. pin 40 and pin 34 for black wire and using these values beeper didn't made a sound

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz don't use the connector, stick hook-up wires from the connector into the GPIO pins

Comment: Do note that this will not play a sound. You'd have to rattle the GPIO on and off very quickly.

Comment: Also note that you might not get a very smooth sound out of the Raspberry PIs GPIO pins if your system is under load. If you want really good quality sound, you need dedicated hardware or a realtime operating system.

Comment: Also also note that you might want to add a resistor between the speaker and the GPIO, to prevent too much current flowing. Without a resistor, you might permanently damage the speaker and the raspberry pi.

Comment: Which errors do you want to signal and how do you plan to detect them?

Comment: @NonStandardModel I'm guessing this is in response to my answer. I don't know. OP wasn't clear. I'm not sure they know. I'm not familiar with Python but if there's a try/catch structure I'd take a guess at that.

Comment: A different perspective on the comment by @Distjubo: You really should check the voltage and current ratings on the speaker.  The GPIO pin is going to provide 3.3 V and limited current.  If your speaker requires more than that, you may not get a sound in any case, and you might damage hardware trying.